# shave the money vs. save the money

Tags: phrase-meaning

Is "shave the money" actually "save the money"? Or is the former a humorous way of the latter?

DuckDuckGo tweeted:

> "You should take steps to limit Facebook’s data collection. While you can **shave the money** FB makes selling ads targeted to your interests, this tactic isn’t as effective as spending less time—or no time at all—on the service."

Source: [Twitter](https://twitter.com/DuckDuckGo/status/1346105861169676290)

Comment: ***Shaving money*** is usually what drunkards do when they switch from champagne to cheap cider! Other than that, it's just a coincidence that highly metaphoric ***shave***  sounds a lot like the normal verb ***save*** that we might have expected before ***money***. The *semantic* difference between ***saving*** and ***saving*** here isn't really worth setting out (when you "shave" numeric values, you're just reducing therm by a little bit, which in this context amounts to "saving" that little bit of reduction).

Comment: ,,,it probably wasn't *intended* - it just came out that way. If the writer had intended ***save***, he wouldn't have included the article in ***the** money FB makes*.

Comment: Note that the tweeter here is talking about ***shaving = reducing*** the amount of money Facebook make by selling adverts. Which really has nothing to do with ***saving money*** (= reducing one's own ***expenditure***, not reducing Facebook's ad income) because ***it doesn't "cost" anything to use Facebook anyway***.

Answer (score 2):

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/shave#:%7E:text=If%20you%20shave%20a%20small,reduce%20it%20by%20that%20amount.):

> If you shave a small amount off something such as a record, cost, or
> price, you reduce it by that amount.

- She's already shaved four seconds off the national record for the mile.
- Supermarket chains have shaved prices.

You can also check this [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Shaving%20money) entry.

***Shave time, shave money*** seems to be a slogan commonly used in adverts for razor blades and it is a funny word play. Consider:

> Dollar Shave Club is a new membership-only website that promises to
> ***“shave time, shave money”*** by sending customers a shipment of razor
> blades automatically every month. The company estimates that it will
> save members as much as $292 per year on shaving.

(from [latimes.com](https://www.latimes.com/business/technology/la-fi-tn-dollar-shave-club-20120305-story.html), a business oriented site)